# model property count 0 in controller asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

these are my models.

```
public class Question
{

    private string _questionNo;  
    private string _questionText; 
    private List<Option> _options;

    public List<Option> Options
    {
        get { return _options; }
        set { _options = value; }
    }
    public string QuestionNo
    {
        get { return _questionNo; }
        set { _questionNo = value; }
    } 
    public string QuestionText
    {
        get { return _questionText; }
        set { _questionText = value; }
    } 
}

public class Option
{

    private string _optionText; 
    private string _optionNumber; 
    public string OptionText
    {
        get { return _optionText; }
        set { _optionText = value; }
    }
    public string OptionNumber
    {
        get { return _optionNumber; }
        set { _optionNumber = value; }
    } 
}
```

this is my controller.

```
    public ActionResult GetQuestion()
    {
        Question_Data ques = new Question_Data();
        var vewmodel = ques.GetQuestion("99916939-D916-4CAE-B527-1A0CD8A3C09D", "AAFA7A2B-D840-4202-B38F-563254FF8B63", 1);
       return View(vewmodel);
    }
    public ActionResult SaveDropDown(Question question)
    {

    }
```

this is view

```
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveDropDown", "GetQuestion", Model))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <fieldset>
            <label class="select">@Model.QuestionText
            </label>
            <select name="selectedObjects" id="selectchoice1">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Options)
                {         
                    <option  value="@item.OptionNumber">@item.OptionText</option>
                }
            </select>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

everything looks fine. when i click the create button in view it is  going to the SaveDropDown in controller but its showing the List of options  with null.

i have defined the List of options  in Question class. it has to show but its not showing any options. why it is behaving like that. whats the solution for it.

Thanks.

---

this is what i am getting in form post

```
      <form method="post" action="/GetQuestion/SaveDropDown?Options=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5Bsd.mvc.Models.Option%5D&QuestionNo=136&QuestionText=What%20is%20your%20current%20relationship%20status%3F&QuestionType=2">
```

only question related properties are posted.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question: are you saying that initially, the page is okay (it appears, the drop down box contains all options), but there is a problem after you click the _Create_ button? If yes, what's the code of the _SaveDropDown_ method? It's empty in the question and won't compile like that. When is the pasted view used (as the initial page, or when you click the _Create_ button, or both)?

Comment: when i click create button, in the SaveDropDown method.its showing question.Options.count =0. how could i get that question.Options ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely that the auto-binder doesn't understand how to map "selectedObjects" to "question" by the names you've assigned.

The model binder is going to look for form fields prefixed with the variable name of the object you specify in the controller action. In your case, the model binder is looking for fields called "question.*".

Is there a reason your not using the built in field helpers in MVC? Those will help to generate the correct naming convention for the model binder to pickup.

Can you better describe what you're trying to do? Is the goal of this form to allow a user to enter in options, click add and have it save them? Or is the goal for the user to see a list of options, select one and post the answer back?

One of the key reasons that the List is null is there are no form fields that represent the collection of options.

Comment: k. My aim is to create survey type of questions. i started with select option. I am getting the question and Options from the server in the XML format and serializing it to the model and binding it to the view.   so i have to save the user options back to the server. so i am editing the List of Options and again serializing to XML and going back to server and saving them. but here one question can be render at a time. so based on questionNo and QuestionType am doing all this. is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your response sooner. Are you working on the admin portion of managing the questions/answers or are you working on the part where the user is answering the survey?

Comment: In most cases you'll want to seperate your entity models (List of Questions) from what you'll be sending you your view (View Model). Is there a paticular reason you want to post back a List of options? What are you going to do with them? With hidden fields named Options[0].OptionText and Options[0].OptionName and Options[1].OptionText and Options[1].OptionName the model binder would auto-generate your List<Option>. You could build a custom Display Template or Editor Template that would generate the hidden HTML of your Options.

Comment: working on the part where the user is answering the survey. i am equating the oprtions with the selected objects and making IsAnswer property to true in the Option. finally i am building the XML with question and Option and giving it to service.

Answer (score 1):

please tell what was ur expectation. To which property in class `Question` do you  want to bind the selected option.

**Or**  Do this

```
 public ActionResult SaveDropDown(Question question, string selectedObjects)
    {
            //use selectedObjects property to read the chosen option
    }
```

Comment: i want the QuestionNo and selected Options properties of Question.

Answer (score 0):

Your action method accepts an instance of type "Question". Check out the data that is being passed as "FORM" data using FireBug and see if that data can be mapped into "Question" model object.

Comment: hi pavan this is what i am getting in form post

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add a `SelectedOption` property to your model

```
public class Question
{

    private string _questionNo;  
    private string _questionText; 
    private List<Option> _options;
    private Option _selectedOption;


    public Option SelectedOption
    {
        get { return _selectedOption; }
        set { _selectedOption = value; }
    }
    public List<Option> Options
    {
        get { return _options; }
        set { _options = value; }
    }
    public string QuestionNo
    {
        get { return _questionNo; }
        set { _questionNo = value; }
    } 
    public string QuestionText
    {
        get { return _questionText; }
        set { _questionText = value; }
    } 
}
```

And in your View use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(t=>Model.SelectedOption.OptionNumber
                       ,new SelectList(Model.Options
                                       , "OptionNumber"
                                       , "OptionText"))
```

Also, you are passing your `Model` as a route value parameter in your `BeginForm` statment - may be a source of issues.